# DataGridComboBoxColumn cell not displaying selected item text?

Tags: wpf, .net-4.0, datagrid, datagridcomboboxcolumn

I was wondering how you get the DataGridComboBoxColumn to display the selected item text when it is not in editing mode? And also is it possible to make it so the combo box in edit mode displays the selected item text initially?

Here is my XAML:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Formatter" 
                        SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=Format}">
  <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="">
      <Setter Property="Text" Value="{Binding Path=FormatView.Name}" />
    </Style>
  </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
  <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
      <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DefinedFormatters}" />
      <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True" />
      <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
          <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>
          </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
</DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Comment: look at this answer  
this most to help u
                                                              
[http://stackoverflow.com/a/27408768/4048306][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27408768/4048306

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was the only resource on DataGridComboBoxColumn that I found helpful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcomboboxcolumn.aspx

Everything else (that I found on non-MSDN sites) was **misleading**!

Answer (score 4):

Ok I figured it out after a lot of googling.

but it seems you just do the same thing for ElementStyle, again with the target type of combo box, even though it does not seem to show a ComboBox when not editing.

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Formatter" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=Format}">
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DefinedFormatters}" />
                <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
                <Setter Property="ItemsSource" Value="{Binding Path=DefinedFormatters}" />
                <Setter Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True" />
                <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
    </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite at a loss, but maybe try the following: Remove the ElementStyle and instead set the DisplayMemberPath, e.g.:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Formatter" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=Format}" DisplayMemberPath="Name">
```

Path might also be FormatView.Name, I don't have a clear picture of your data structure. And how did you set the ItemsSource of your DataGridComboBoxColumn?

Comment: code example added, unfortunatly I can't verify syntactical correctness right now

Comment: That didn't help, let me also clarify that, the combo box is working and it is sucessfully binding the values to the data context, only problem is it is not displaying the text for its currently selected value, just a blank cell. Thanks,

Comment: So if you select a new value and then stop editing, the correct value is displayed?

Comment: The Visual Studio Output shows no Binding Expression Errors? And I noticed that the TargetType of the DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle is an empty string, which doesn't even compile in my studio. What does it say in your code?

Comment: I have another idea, although I'm growing more desperate ;)

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply, but I figured it out, just had to do a lot of googling, see my answer.