# Text entered in WPF DatagridTextboxColumn and value selected in DatagridComboboxColumn are not displayed when focus is lost

Tags: wpf, vb.net, dynamic, wpfdatagrid

My question might seem repeatetive as there are similar questions in StackOverflow like,

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5733782/how-to-retain-value-in-datagridcomboboxcolumn-of-wpfs-datagrid

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6101441/creating-wpf-datagrid-dynamically-with-dynamically-created-drop-down-box-using-d

but I cudn't find an answer pertaining to my requirements.

I generate a WPF datagrid dynamically which takes columns from a metadata file(excel) based on certain conditions. The datagrid needs to be generic and hence I cannot bind the Datagrid itself during creation. I bind the DatagridCombobobox columns dynamically and was able to get the values in them too.

Now my problem is, once I select a value in the DatagridCombobobox or enter text in the DatagridTextboxColumn and then move to another cell/ row, this text and selection disappears.

How do I enable the Datagrid cell/row to remember my entered text or selection dynamically?
I checked the answer of a similar question in [DataGridComboBoxColumn cell not displaying selected item text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6517346/wpf-datagridcomboboxcolumn-cell-not-displaying-selected-item-text) but it is for a static datagrid. Since my datagrid creation is dynamic, I donot know how to use this solution. Kindly help. 
I am stuck up in this and its taking a lot of my time :(

Regards,
Niranjan.

Dynamic DataGrid creation:

```
    Dim setupGrid = "<my:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns='False' Name='grdSetup' " & "xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'" & "  xmlns:sdk = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk'" & "  xmlns:x = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'" & "  xmlns:TAB = 'http://fabtab.codeplex.com'" & "   xmlns:my='http://schemas.microsoft.com/wpf/2008/toolkit' " & " >"
    setupGrid = setupGrid & "<my:DataGrid.Columns>"
    ...
    ...
    ...
    setupGrid = setupGrid & "</my:DataGrid.Columns>"

    setupGrid = setupGrid & "</my:DataGrid>"

    Dim sr = New MemoryStream(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(setupGrid))
    Dim pc = New ParserContext()
    pc.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation")
    pc.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml")
    Dim grdElement As UIElement = DirectCast(System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Load(sr, pc), UIElement)
    Dim grdSetup As DataGrid = DirectCast(grdElement, DataGrid)
```

My DataGridCombobox code is similar :

```
    setupGrid = setupGrid & "<my:DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name='" & dr.Item("ParameterName").ToString.Trim & "'  Header='" & dr.Item("ParameterName") & "'  SelectedValuePath='" & dr.Item("ValueColumn") & "' DisplayMemberPath='" & dr.Item("DisplayColumn") & "'  />"
```

This string value will be added to the above DataGrid string and converted to UIElement as shown in the above DataGrid code. I add my Datagrid to an ItemsControl dynamically :

```
    Me.DynamicContent.Items.Add(grdElement)
```

where DynamicContent is ItemsControl.

In the UserControl_Loaded event, I find each ComboBox in my Datagrid thru :

```
    Dim dynamicGrid as DataGrid = DynamicContent.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(0)
    Dim comboColumns = dynamicGrid.Columns.OfType(Of DataGridComboBoxColumn)()
    For index As Integer = 0 To comboColumns.Count - 1
     comboColumns(index).ItemsSource = DirectCast(dt, IListSource).GetList()
    Next
```

where dt is a Datatable which consists of data to be to my ComboBox. It has the SelectedValuePath and DisplayMember path of the combobox as the columns.

I cannot set the SelectedItemBinding and the SelectedValueBinding for the DatagridComboboxColumn before hand as it is dynamic and varies for different ComboColumns. I dont know how these can be set in the above loaded event. 
Pls let me know what I am doing wrong? Or what can be done so that I can be able to retain the values even after the focus is lost.
Sorry for the lengthy description :(

Comment: Please post XAML/Code for your ComboBox. My best guess is you are not binding either `SelectedItem`, `SelectedIndex`, or `SelectedValue` so  your selection is not getting saved.